# Set the z-index of an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an OpenLayers map and I try to implement a "lightbox" image gallery , in the same page.

By "lightbox" image gallery" I mean that the images/arrows/exit button cover the whole screen.

The problem is that OpenLayers map covers the lightbox gallery (see image).

I have set `z-index` to the map and to the lightbox `div`s, like so

```
<div id='map_element' style='width: 900px; height: 400px; z-index:1;'> </div>

//and then for lightbox
#imagegal2 img {
 height:85%;    
 z-index:90;    
}
```

And this does not work

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For z-Index to work, you must have explicitly positioned the elements in CSS or InLine Style statements or it will be ignored:

```
z-index only works on positioned elements
(position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed
```

Ref [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I have written down a small piece of code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhatabbas/GD4de/5/) please have look it might be helpful for you.

**Sample Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>- jsFiddle demo by farhatabbas</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
<style type='text/css'>
#map {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});

var map, layer;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(
                new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    map.getProjectionObject()
                ), 4
            );    
        }
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
</body>
</html>
```